# Bootstrap: Text navbar-text wrong color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I would like to include as a title of a navigation bar some image plus some text. I am following the [Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) but the resulting text 'Custom Text' in paragraph is not displayed with the same format (color, size) as the other elements of the navigation bar.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                <img alt="logotitle" src="logo.png">
            </a>
                <p class="navbar-text">Custom text</p>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">activeitem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">navitem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">navitem2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">navitem3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you also provide your CSS please? With ctrl+M you can put your snippet of code to run here also.

Comment: Only CSS used is the Bootstrap CSS provided with the HTML document code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first you are using bootstrap 3 and navbar-light class is a bootstrap 4 class and basically does nothing in bootstrap 3 you are looking for navbar-defalut in bootstrap 3.  Then if I understand what you are trying to do if you want your text to basically be the navbar-brand just put that text in the navbar-brand and custom color it from there in your css.  If you don't want it a custom color then don't worry about adding the color to the navbar-brand.  You will just need to change your image to `display:inline-block` and the you can eliminate all of the extra stuff you have going on in your navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://placehold.it/20x20"/> Your Text</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">activeitem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">navitem1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">navitem2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">navitem3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And Css

```
.navbar-brand img{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
  color:green;
}
```

Here is a demo [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/jf6bk1ko/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">

    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a href="#">
        <img alt="logotitle" src="logo.png">
      </a> 
          <span id="target"> Custom Text </span>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
   ...
```

Add the css, manually it will save you time
`#target { color: #337ab7; }`
[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObWoPO)

Comment: But i want the Custom Text to be displayed as the title of the bar with the image, as a navbar-brand, there are examples and also I would like it to be displayed with the same font color as the other elements. Something like this [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObWoPO ] but I want the Custom Text not to be a link.

Comment: I get it now. Can you access my demo link? Because I can't access yours :(

Comment: `<div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#">
                <img alt="logotitle" src="logo.png"> 
            </a>
             Custom Text
            </div>

Comment: I use the same line that the one above for the demo but the Custom Text is displayed in black color. Not sure if what I want can be done in a straighforward way!.